# Python input validation: how to limit user input to a specific range of integers?

Tags: python, validation, input, exception

Beginner here, looking for info on input validation.

I want the user to input two values, one has to be an integer greater than zero, the next an integer between 1-10. I've seen a lot of input validation functions that seem over complicated for these two simple cases, can anyone help?

For the first number (integer greater than 0, I have):

```
while True:
    try:
        number1 = int(input('Number1: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("Not an integer! Please enter an integer.")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

This also doesn't check if it's positive, which I would like it to do. And I haven't got anything for the second one yet. Any help appreciated!

Comment: why not just check `if number1 < 0` than raise error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add in a simple if statement and raise an Error if the number isn't within the range you're expecting

```
while True:
    try:
        number1 = int(input('Number1: '))
        if number1 < 1 or number1 > 10:
            raise ValueError #this will send it to the print message and back to the input option
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid integer. The number must be in the range of 1-10.")
```

Comment: The raise ValueError if statement was what I was missing, thanks!

Comment: This will send the control to the except block and then back to the start of the loop. Notice I've changed some code too - i.e the else block was removed and also the continue. You don't need to explicitly call continue unless you want to skip some code. Otherwise the loop will continue naturally

Answer (score 2):

Use `assert`:

```
while True:
    try:
        number1 = int(input('Number1: '))
        assert 0 < number1 < 10
    except ValueError:
        print("Not an integer! Please enter an integer.")
    except AssertionError:
        print("Please enter an integer between 1 and 10")
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomError(Exception):
   pass

while True:
    try:
       number1 = int(raw_input('Number1: '))
       if number1 not in range(0,9):
         raise CustomError
    break
except ValueError:
    print("Numbers only!")
except CustomError:
    print("Enter a number between 1-10!)
```